# Completely disable autocomplete in Mac Mail

Tags: mail.app, email, contacts

I use mail 8.2 on OS X 10.10.  Due to new corporate policy at my office, no autocompletion is allowed in e-mail clients (except maybe for address fetching from the corporate address book via exchange: it's not clear).

Is it possible to disable either autocompletion entirely, or the addition of people to the autocompletion list?

Answer (score 1):

May be this discussion will help you:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6861390?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Unfortunately not.  The issue is not that _I_ don't want autocorrect, it's that the company does not.  Merely not using it is insufficient to appease them.